# Vue form not showing up

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I tried to create a Products form using VueJS, but when I refresh my localhost, it's just a blank page.[the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dhZb.png)

I have turned off XAMPP and turned it on again but still, it's just a blank page that showing

Here's my code:

ApiCalling.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="api-calling container mt-5">
        <h1>Create Product</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input v-model="product.name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input v-model="product.price" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price...">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="createProduct">Create</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                product: {
                    name: '',
                    price: 0
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async createProduct() {
                try {
                    const response = await axios.post('/products', {
                      name: this.product.name,
                      price: this.product.pric
                    })
                    console.log(response.data.product)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

app.js :

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';


const app = createApp({});

import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
app.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);


app.mount('#app');
Vue.component('api-calling', require('./components/ApiCalling.vue').default)
```

welcome.blade.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>
        </style>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <api-calling></api-calling>
        </div>
        <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
      
    </body>
</html>
```

what did I do wrong? or is it am i using codes that only works on older version of Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues in your code:

```
price: this.product.pric
```

should be:

```
price: this.product.price
```

in app.js you are mixing vue2 and vue3, I think that you want to use vue3, so it should look like:

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';

import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
import ApiCalling from './components/ApiCalling.vue';

const app = createApp({});

app.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);
app.component('api-calling', ApiCalling);

app.mount('#app');
```

And finally:

In your ApiCalling.vue component, you are using axios but it doesn't seem to be imported. You need to import axios at the top of your script:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```